# Unable to set policy for user using MinIO client, getting user does not exists in ldap error even though user exists in LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, minio

Error:
mc:  Unable to set the policy. The specified user does not exist. (Specified user does not exist).

---

Details:

After configuring MiniIo with LDAP server, when I try to login with user, am getting error saying to add policy for user.

[image]

The same user when i tried to set policy using minioclient(mc), am getting error saying user doesn't exists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

play is the default alias(server connection) comes up with minio client.

I first had to create an alias using minio client to connect to my minio server and then set policy like below,

```
mc alias set <ALIAS> <YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT> [YOUR-ACCESS-KEY] [YOUR-SECRET-KEY] [--api API-SIGNATURE]
e.g., mc alias set minioserverxyz http://192.168.1.51 BKIKJAA5BMMU2RHO6IBB V7f1CwQqAcwo80UEIJEjc5gVQUSSx5ohQ9GSrr12 --api S3v4
#Then
mc admin policy set minioserverxyz readwrite user="{ldap-user}"
```